# XML Nodes differ from Php Soap

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

Hi guys I am new to xml and I am curious if there is any difference between the 2 codes above:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns......>
  <gro:GetGeography>
    <gro:request>
      <gro:ClientIPAddress>?</gro:ClientIPAddress>
    </gro:request>
  </gro:GetGeography>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns......> 
 <ns1:GetGeography>
    <ns1:request>
      <ns1:ClientIPAddress>?</ns1:ClientIPAddress>
    </ns1:request>
  </ns1:GetGeography>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So I have to make a request like the first one but SoapClient on Php is creating the code like the bottom one.

Is there any difference? e.g First one has `gro:` and the second `ns1:`.

Also I can see that `<soapenv>` is different to second `<SOAP_ENV>` is it Case Sensitive?

I am not getting any response but I am not sure if the problem is here or on the rest of the code. But I am curious is there any difference on these I mentioned before? If yes what the way to change them in Php?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is the same.

`soapenv` and `SOAP-ENV` are aliases for the actual namespace `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/`. The XML parser will read the namespace definitions and match the namespace values. In PHP DOM you will find the namespace in the `$namespaceURI` property.

The following 4 examples can all be read as `{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/}Envelope`:

- `<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"/>`
- `<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"/>`
- `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"/>`
- `<Envelope
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"/>`

The namespace prefixes can be redefined on any element node. Namespaces need to be unique, so they tend to be long and complex. To make the XML easier to read (and smaller) aliases are used as tag prefixes.

Comment: Thanks @ThW thats helpfull